# Перестали работать pipeline на Jekins: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.Nonnull

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

Ищу помощи с переставшими работать пайплайнами на "Дженкинс" - предположительно, после обновления соответствующих плагинов (Pipeline).

При запуске любого задания типа pipeline, даже "Hello World" шаблона, в Console Output появляются следующие ошибки:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 43: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.Nonnull
 @ line 43, column 1.
   import javax.annotation.Nonnull
   ^

jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 42: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.CheckForNull
 @ line 42, column 1.
   import javax.annotation.CheckForNull
   ^

jar:file:/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/pipeline-model-definition/WEB-INF/lib/pipeline-model-definition.jar!/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/modeldefinition/ModelInterpreter.groovy: 455: unable to resolve class javax.annotation.CheckForNull ,  unable to find class for annotation
 @ line 455, column 30.
       def withCredentialsBlock(@CheckForNull Environment environment, Closure body) {
```

**Что пробовал:**

- Удаление плагина "Pipeline: Declarative Agent API", помеченного как устаревший.
- Установку через hpi-файл плагина "Pipeline: Model API", который рекомендуется для замены устаревшего "Pipeline: Declarative Agent API".
- Даунгрейд плагина "Pipeline: Declarative Agent API".
- Обновление java на сервере с Jenkins.
- Обновление самого Jenkins (не потребовалось - установлена последняя версия)
- Читал записи с баг-трекера, но ничего конкретного не смог найти.

**Данные по системе:**

- Версия Jenkins: 2.235.1
- Версия java: openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
- Список плагинов Pipeline и их версии:

````
    
Pipeline Graph Analysis Plugin 1.10     
    
Pipeline: API 2.40      
    
Pipeline: Basic Steps 2.20  
    
Pipeline: Build Step 2.12       
    
Pipeline: Declarative 1.7.0     
    
Pipeline: Declarative Agent API 1.1.1       
    
Pipeline: Declarative Extension Points API 1.7.0    
    
Pipeline: Groovy 2.81   
    
Pipeline: Input Step 2.11       
    
Pipeline: Job 2.39  
    
Pipeline: Milestone Step 1.3.1      
    
Pipeline: Model API 1.7.0   
    
Pipeline: Multibranch 2.21      
    
Pipeline: Nodes and Processes 2.35      
    
Pipeline: REST API Plugin 2.13      
    
Pipeline: SCM Step 2.11 
    
Pipeline: Shared Groovy Libraries 2.16      
    
Pipeline: Stage Step 2.5    
    
Pipeline: Stage Tags Metadata 1.7.0 
    
Pipeline: Stage View Plugin 2.13        
    
Pipeline: Step API 2.22     
    
Pipeline: Supporting APIs 3.5```
````

Comment: Ошибся в одном из пунктов: даунгрейдил плагин "Pipeline: Model API" до версии 1.6.0, но это не помогало, так как от версии 1.7.0 была куча зависимостей. Приходилось ставить обратно последнюю версию.

Comment: Нашел титек на баг-трекере: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62988